# Notation for action attribute in Django forms

Tags: django, forms

I'm learning about Django forms and while following the tutorial (for v1.11), it says to use dot notation when setting the value for the form action attribute. For example `<form action="{% url 'myapp.views.detail' %}>`

This didn't work for me. While trying to figure out how to fix my issue I noticed different people used different notation to set the form action attribute.

Some used `<form action="{% /your-name/ %}">`, some would use just `<form action="{% detail %}">`. What ended up working for me was  `<form action="{% myapp:detail %}">`.

Can somebody clarify what the differences between the different notations?

Answer (score 1):

form `action` is just an attribute that will be assigned by the URL where you will handle data from the `form`.
So it can be whatever, you just need to know the correct URL that will retrieve these data.

`action = ''` means the current URL
`action = '.'` means the current Directory ending with the last slash `/`

`action = '/url/to/somethin/'`normal URL
`action = '{% url 'django_url' arg.pk %}'` Django URL

Comment: But what I don't understand is why there are different `django_url` notations?

Comment: you will always find them prefixed by `url`, Django perhaps with many different notations, does things easier. Just use what looks easier, nicer to you....

Comment: That's the problem though. Not all of them worked for me. Only 1 out of the ones I listed did and it wasn't mentioned in the documentation. I'm trying to figure out why.